# this.setState making infinite loop outside of array.map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I have this array map function for rendering some stuff... 
I have 5 variables that start from 0 and depending on a switch statement each variable value is increased by 1.

```
renderUser = (index)=>{
    let C1Count = 0, C2Count = 0, C3Count = 0, C4Count = 0, C5Count = 0;
    let users = this.state.users.map((user,index)=>{

   // swiching some value , that is from 0 to 4

   switch(this.state.users[index].result){
      case 0: { C1Count += 1;   break; }
      case 1: { C2Count += 1;  break; }
      case 2: { C3Count += 1;  break; }
      case 3: { C4Count += 1;   break; }
      case 4: { C5Count += 1;   break; }
      default: { console.log("non");  break; };
    }
    return(
      ....stuff to render 
                   )


   }).reverse();



  return users;
```

}

I want to update 5 states

```
this.setState({
C1Count:C1Count, // state : variable value
C2Count:C2Count, // state : variable value
C3Count:C3Count, // state : variable value
C4Count:C4Count, // state : variable value
C5Count:C5Count  // state : variable value
});
```

If i place the setState code after `...}).reverse();` and before  `..return users;`

I get a

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

error .... so my question is ... how to update the state AFTER all the loops are finished and the `C1Count, C2Count, C3Count, C4Count, C5Count` variables are updated.

Answer (score 3):

When you `setState()`, you will cause another render hence your infinite loop. You shouldn't call `setState` from `render`. One of the [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) methods (componentDidMount etc) would be a better place depending on your needs or the `constructor` if this is the initial state of the component.

Comment: yep .. I managed to do the wanted actions with global variables `this.C1Count , this.C2Count e.t.`

Answer (score 0):

By default, a React Component will re-render when its state is changed through `setState()`, which is why `render()` should be a pure function (i.e., do not modify state).

For your case, `Count` variables are derived state, so you wouldn't need to actually keep the value. Instead, you could create a function that calculated its value:

```
getCounts() {
  return this.state.users.reduce((counts, user) => {
    switch (user.result) {
      case 0: 
        counts.C1Count++; break;
      case 1:
        counts.C2Count++; break;
      case 2:
        counts.C3Count++; break;
      case 3:
        counts.C4Count++; break;
      case 4:
        counts.C5Count++; break;
      default:
        console.log("non");
    }

    return counts;
  }, { C1Count: 0, C2Count: 0, C3Count: 0, C4Count: 0, C5Count: 0 });
}
```